# Python Nmap - Argument Parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, optparse

I'm trying to improve my python and working with the Violent Python book to help me do that.

One of the tasks is to create a Python nmap scanner, which I've done and can successfully scan a host, checking against a list of ports.  However, the scanner is using the default `-sV` switch for version scanning, however I want to try and implement a way to change the type of scan that the user wants to run, i.e. `-sU` for UDP etc...

My code is available at: https://absentia.mycorneroftheinter.net/james/violentPythonScripts/src/master/chapter2/pyPortScanNmap.py

(It is a self-signed cert, so you will get a warning...)

Back to my question... when I try and code the option for a specify a different scanning option, such as `-sU` for UDP, the program crashes out saying that another argument is required  - which is the IP address of the host to scan, however I would have already specified that using the `-H 172.16.133.136` switch.

I think that I have missed something when I try and put different scan functionality in, because I thought specifying a different switch would just replace the default scan type that nmap.py uses(?)

Can someone shed any light on where I have gone wrong?  You can see in the code I have comments where I have tried to implement the additional option, but alas, not successfully.

---

EDIT: 
As per the comments below, when I supply the `--ping` switch for example, and then supply a random value to this, I get the following stack trace error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyPortScanNmap.py", line 88, in <module>
    main()
  File "pyPortScanNmap.py", line 62, in main
    parser.add_option("", dest = 'tcpScan', type = 'string', help = 'Run TCP Scan') # Run a TCP scan against the specified host(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1013, in add_option
    option = self.option_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 566, in __init__
    opts = self._check_opt_strings(opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 586, in _check_opt_strings
    raise TypeError("at least one option string must be supplied")
TypeError: at least one option string must be supplied
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: `optparse` has been deprecated in favor of [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) since Python 2.7. There are other options --- the excellent [`docopt`](http://docopt.org), for example.

Comment: Ah right, thanks.  i was told that `arparse` was actually not as good, but I will make a note of it and look to change in the future, if needs be :)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your error?

Comment: I don't actually get a stack trace, I think because there is just no argument supplied with the option.  I just get the following: `pyPortScanNmap.py: error: --ping option requires an argument`.

Comment: The stack trace I get if I supply a random value to the `--ping` switch is in the original question (too long for a comment)

Comment: It seems you want `--ping` to be a [boolean option](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#handling-boolean-flag-options).

Comment: Admittedly, at the moment my wording is incorrect on the variables, basically the `--ping` switch should make the nmap scan run the `--sP` scan against the target specified in `-H`, but it keeps asking me to specify an additional argument, when it has been supplied in a different switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121556/discussion-between-alberto-garcia-raboso-and-james).